# what is the criteria to choose encryption algorithm for my system

Tags: java, encryption, password-hash

I am working on a system which is going to be applied in the real environment. I need to make high security mechanism for the system, one of them is encryption for user's passwords in my database.

I prefer to use one way encryption method to two way encryption, the problem is I want to choose a good algorithm which has good performance and have reasonable reasons to convince my partners why i choose one algorithm instead of other.

Can you give me some tips for doing that?

Comment: why you prefer encryption over "cryptographic hash function" ? If you prefer encryption, there are plenty of algos, but what are your goals? Performance, space,....?

Comment: I presume you want to store the passwords for verification only? Or do you want to store them so users can retrieve their values? The answers very much depend on the use case.

Answer (score 3):

Don't just use a simple one-way hash.

Use something like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29#Blowfish-based_scheme) instead. I'm sure there will be good, free, off-the-shelf implementations available for Java (assuming that they're not already included in the JRE itself).

Comment: PBKDF2 is - using algorithm string `"PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1"` - but bcrypt isn't, and isn't in Bouncy Castle neither for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what kind of argument you're looking for but :

SHA is a good one-way hash functions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm

Edit :

- I'm using Bcrypt but maybe you should look at Scrypt (http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2012/03/dont-use-bcrypt.html)

Comment: i don't get what u mean by argument ?

Comment: As an argument to present to your partners to choose one algorithm opposed to another.

Comment: Actually i am working on my graduation project and I have to tell my partners why i make every line in the code in order to be ready to discuss it in front of doctors and professors :)